# Couting the number of paragraphs in a text file without \n - having trouble with indexes

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, text, count

This is a basic question and I'm probably forgeting something essential, but I would really appreciate some help!

I have a text file of a book that is stores in a variable as a list of strings. Each string represents a line in the book. When the line is empty (''), it means that it is the end of a paragraph and a new one starts next.

I have to find how many times two certain words appear in the same paragraph. For this, I want to create a list where each element is a different paragraph. Either that, or store a full paragraph at a time and chech for the words, paragraph by paragraph.

```
def SameParag(filename):


    book = readText('book.txt')
    l= []
    count= 0
    
    for line in book:
        if line != '':        #if the line is not empty
            l.append(line)    #add it to the list 
        else:
            break

    if 'word1' in l and 'word2' in l:
        count = count +1
    
    return count
```

With this, I was trying to story 1 full paragraph in the list l, and then check for the words in that list, but it's returning count=0 (the answer is 8) and the list l is empty.

Answer (score 0):

`in` operator will compare the whole value of each value in the list. You have list of strings, and you are trying to find a small subset of a single string in list of strings and thus, your count will be zero. Example;

```
>>> "foo" in ["foo bar baz", "make bar not foo"]
False
>>>
```

That evaluates to False because "foo" is neither "for bar baz" nor it aint "make bar not foo".

To solve your issue, convert your variable `l` to a string.

```
>>> "foo" in "".join(["foo bar baz", "make bar not foo"])
True
>>>
```

or just init the `l` as empty string and concat the values into it inside the loop.